# Twitter Bootstrap 3 navigation bar is not responsive

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3. I'm writing a simple navbar but is not responsive: if I zoom in the browser the Toggle navigation doesn't work. You can copy and paste this html file and zooming with Chrome the toogle doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-us">
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Title</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting to include Jquery!  Add this in your head tags.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I `zoom` in the browser and the Toggle navigation worked. May be some other problem you are facing.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/4RhhF/22/)

[image: without zoom]

[image: with zoom]

Comment: This works in Jsfiddle, but not in a real application because jsfiddle automatically includes jquery.

Comment: Fiddle does not include jquery automatically, I actually included jquery in fiddle, you can see in the left..:)